# How to get View of group or child item?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have question. Is possible to get View of Group or Child in ExpandableListView but not in click handler.
I need to set background color to some row in simple function

Comment: Can you explain more what you are trying to do? We generally use adapter to set differentiating properties to the row at time of row creation.

Comment: Hi Chintrashu!
I need just get view from ExpandableListView that change background color. I know that I can do it in handler where I have reference on View but can I do it just in simple function?Yes I have adapter

Comment: Why are you not setting the background while creating the row?

Comment: Because I have thread which started on another activity and when finished should select some background. Actually I can reset adapter and put logic in those functions those you say but this is not elegant. Is possible to get view and change background?

Comment: Have a look at this post. http://stackoverflow.com/a/21550892/1537997 it shows how to get visible first visible group. Once you get this, you can perform list.getChildCount and detrmine whether the groups/childs you are interested are visible. If they are visible you can perform list.getchildat to get the row.