# expandablelist view scrolling position

Tags: android, listview, scrollview, expandablelistview

I am trying to keep my last scrolled position and populate the adapter with new data but same scrolling position. In my scenerio, I have updating expandable `listview` every 5 second and updating new items very 5 seconds but with last scrolling position left by user.

I have searched a lot about it and found few solutions but still it is behaving strangly each time I set scrolling position.

I am trying to achieve it with this method:

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
{
    @Override public void run() {
        state = list.onSaveInstanceState();
            if(settings != null) {
                if (mode.equals("Now")) {
                   info_panel = new esInfoListAdapter(activity, data, expanHash, false, esActivity.lastgrpPosition);
                }
                else {
                    info_panel = new esInfoListAdapter(Activity.this, data, tchildData,  true, lastgrpPosition);
                }
            }
            list.setAdapter(info_panel);
            if(state != null)
                list.onRestoreInstanceState(state);

            info_panel.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
});
```

So this method gets called just before I updating expandable `listview`. So in short in every five seconds. I am using `Parceable` object to save `list.onSaveInstanceState();` and then use `list.onRestoreInstanceState(state);` when updating new data, but the issue is sometimes it works and sometimes not? Am I missing some trick here? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why are you calling your adapter an info panel? That causes for unreadable code. notifyDatasetChanged is not needed if you set a new adapter. Why are you not saving the scroll position and restore it afterwards?

Comment: but how can I save the scroll position that is point, I call info_panal as I have different panels in my activity...

Comment: You put the scroll position in a variable and use that again. I dont understand your different panels but if they are all adapters then call them all adapters.

Comment: Do you mainly need code for getFirstVisiblePosition() and getExpandableListPosition()?

Comment: ok it would be ok if I can have some code snippet or example ..thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have not yet used ExpandableListView yet but I might. I think you should use combination of methods like getFirstVisiblePosition, getLastVisiblePosition, and getExpandableListPosition.  I think getting the groupPosition is sufficient for a user. A link I referenced is [...get index of first/last visible group in an ExpandableListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3594083/how-do-i-get-index-of-first-last-visible-group-in-an-expandablelistview)